# Como se referir a pessoa com quem se está conversando, em Portugal?

Tags: português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas

Sou brasileiro. No Brasil uma forma comum de se referir a outra pessoa com quem se está conversando é pela palavra "você".

- você vai na praia hoje?
- você está linda.
- o que você prefere comer?

Você é bem aceito e não é recebido de forma negativa. É respeitoso, no Brasil.

E no Brasil quando se está falando com alguém de maior autoridade, ou alguém idoso, se diz "o senhor" ou "a senhora", pois denota mais respeito.

Mudei há pouco tempo para Portugal e noto que aqui não se fala "você".

O que usar então, em Portugal?

O "tu" até onde entendo é para quando se tem proximidade ou mais intimidade com o interlocutor.

Mas se eu falo com um jovem ou uma jovem que acabei de conhecer (onde talvez, "o senhor" não caberia) e eu não sei o seu nome, o que uso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Resumindo, o tu é o você do Brasil ;)

Comment: "Você vai na praia" ou "você vai no cinema" é considerado linguajar de quem tem pouca instrução.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A forma de tratamento depende de muitos factores, como a situação social e a classe social, o dialeto e a idade dos falantes.

Do menos para o mais formal, temos *tu*, *você*, e finalmente *o João*, *o pai*, *o senhor*, *a menina*, *o professor*, etc.

Em Lisboa, *tu* usa-se:

- Entre amigos, excepto amigos pouco próximos mais velhos,
- entre familiares com uma relação de sangue próxima e geralmente também de sogros para genros. Os filhos tratarem os pais por *o pai*, os netos por *o avô*, etc., não é comum hoje em dia.
- Ao falar com qualquer criança ou adolescente jovem,
- entre colegas em qualquer escola ou faculdade,
- de professores para alunos, em geral também na faculdade;
- entre colegas de trabalho na maioria das empresas, mesmo de subordinados para superiores (exceto a falar com quadros de topo numa empresa grande),
- para insultar alguém (por exemplo no trânsito),
- em pessoas abaixo de cerca dos 40 que se conheceram em qualquer situação informal (numa festa, num ginásio, no café, etc.); em geral as mais novas (menos de 30) usarão entre si sempre tu a não ser em interações muito formalizadas (atendimento a clientes, por exemplo, e mesmo assim, em certos bares e outros estabelecimentos com um ambiente mais informal, os empregados tratam-te por *tu* e esperam que reciproques).

Em situações de fronteira, *tu* ocorre mais frequentemente se as duas pessoas forem do mesmo sexo ou se forem de uma classe social mais baixa. Por exemplo, um homem a pedir-me um isqueiro na rua (eu sou um homem de 32 anos) trata-me mais frequentemente por tu, mas as mulheres tendem a deixar mais distância, a não ser que sejam muito novas.

*Você* usa-se pouco em Lisboa, eu em particular nunca uso essa forma de tratamento. Mas vê-se:

- de superiores para inferiores hierárquicos, ou entre iguais, em certas empresas,
- entre amigos pouco íntimos/conhecidos mais velhos (> 50 anos),
- de alguns professores universitários para os alunos,
- em geral, entre pessoas com quem se tem alguma familiaridade mas uma relação afastada: por exemplo, entre vizinhos,
- em publicidade.

Usar *você* com pessoas que não se conhece é pouco recomendado. O normal, se não encaixar na lista de casos para *tu*, é omitir qualquer forma de tratamento explícita. Em Portugal pode usar-se *si* / *consigo* em situações não reflexas, para além de *lhe* / *o* e sujeito omisso, que também são possíveis no Brasil, mas pouco usados.

Para o resto dos casos, para além da forma de tratamento poder ser ambígua, usa-se o nome da pessoa (e.g. *A Maria pode chegar aqui?*), *o jovem*, se for uma pessoa mais velha a tratar uma mais nova, ou, um pouco mais formal, *o senhor/a senhora/a menina*.

Comment: Parece contraditório: "Usar você com pessoas que não se conhece é pouco recomendado" e a sua lista.

Comment: @Lambie contraditório com que parte da lista para _você_?

Comment: Um português da região do Minho disse-me, certa vez, que "você" é uma palavra desconhecida em Portugal. Talvez ele nunca tivesse ouvido, e generalizou. Mas, realmente, nas minhas idas relativamente frequentes, nunca alguém se dirigiu a mim dessa forma. E eu,  limito-me a usar tu, o senhor, a senhora, ou o nome da pessoa com quem falo.

Comment: Meus parentes do norte frequentemente dirigem-se a mim pelo meu nome: "o Luís gostaria de ir até tal lugar?"  No princípio achava estranho mas atualmente eu até  uso essa forma de dirigir-me a eles algumas vezes.